# Toggle readonly option for a field based on condition option

Tags: angular-schema-form

In reading the documentation for condition option it only supports hide/show fields based on how the expression for condition evaluates. Looking to see how instead to make a field "read-only" when the condition is met as opposed to removing it from the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your condition is a function with no side-effects (i.e. its output only depends on inputs), you can watch for changes in inputs and re-evaluate condition.

Imagine you have a condition that something needs to display only if both *first name* and *last name* are filled in. Then, you can do something like this:

```
<div ng-if='hasFirstNameAndLastName'>...</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function checkIfHaveFirstNameAndLastName() { 
   $scope.hasFirstNameAndLastName = ($scope.firstName && $scope.lastName);
}

$scope.$watch('firstName', checkIfHaveFirstNameAndLastName);
$scope.$watch('lastName', checkIfHaveFirstNameAndLastName);
```

I was actually thinking about baking something like this into *angular-schema-form* because re-evaluation of **evalExpr()** becomes a problem once application grows in size.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Looks like I did not frame my question correctly. I want to make a field "read-only" when a condition is met. Currently the framework only seems to allow for a way to remove the field from the view or show the field in the view when a condition is met.

Comment: Condition makes a field visible or invisible. You can create 2 fields. One editable. One readonly. Make conditions opposite for these two fields. One will be visible as editable. Another will be visible as readonly.

`[  "switch",
  {
    "key": "email",
    "condition": "!model.switch",
    "readonly": true
  },
  {
    "key": "email",
    "condition": "model.switch"
  }]`

See http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html example "Hack. Conditional required"